# Commenting feature on a Video asset in Sharepoint

Tags: video

I am new to SharePoint 2013. I have managed to get the Latest Video and Playlist displayed on a page.

Is it possible to have a comments feature (pretty much like youtube) on each video?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Note board is an good option. Currently i used Discussion Board feature to add comments for a video assets. I am creating a topic in discussion for each video. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a comments feature just add the `Note Board` Web Part that is under Social Collaboration group.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I dont have note board web part available under Social Collaboration Group, I am using publishing site.